# How to configure lighttpd webserver to run CGI scripts written in C on Ubuntu 14.4?

Tags: ubuntu, cgi, lighttpd

I had a look on a question similar like this one before but it did not work out.
Please if some one tried it before or know how to do it on steps to follow.

Some threads I found but no thing is working for me, such as this one:
[Configuring lighttpd to handle CGI C executables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6267084/configuring-lighttpd-to-handle-cgi-c-executables)

here is what I did exactly:
1- I installed a fresh copy of Ubuntu 14.4 on VM. 
2- I followed the steps found at this URL to install the lighttpd webserver and PHP (Only the Installation part):
https://www.scandio.de/2012/11/setting-up-a-lightweight-webserver-with-lighttpd-php5-and-sqlite3/

3- After I am finished from the installation part, I followed these steps at http://www.acmesystems.it/foxg20_cgi

but I tried several times even many possibilities and trials in changing /etc/lighttpd/lighttpd.conf file but No GAIN ...

Please If some one has an idea, share it 
Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Configuring lighttpd to run CGI written in C is the same as configuring lighttpd to run CGI written in any interpreted language.

`$HTTP["url"] =~ "^/cgi-bin/" { cgi.assign = ( "" => "" ) }`

https://redmine.lighttpd.net/projects/lighttpd/wiki/Docs_ModCGI

You are likely having an issue where your C code is not responding using CGI/1.1 protocol, sending a response header followed by a blank line, and then the response body.